# Get the specific lines in unstructured text files and make them structured in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have some text files. I scraped the data from web. 
And the unit structure of the txt file is as below.

```
**2013/03/13  

Butterf13

*Good morning, now I see some points for your guys. Good thing. Wow It’s very nice to see you and keep going on your task but you got the roll pie* 

More 

Reply**
```

The first line is about time and second line is for nickname of user. And last two lines (More; Reply) for just options (like see more, reply to this comment). The problem is that I want to get the only comment that is tilted.

The data look like this,

```
2013/03/13

Butterf13

Good morning, now I see some points for your guys. Good thing. Wow It’s very nice to see you and keep going on your task but you got the roll pie 

More 

Reply 

2013/03/14

Bear123

Good

Now I can see that : )  

More 

Replies 4 Reply

2013/03/13

dkerf1

now 

I see some points for your guys. 

Good thing. 
Wow
It’s very nice to see you and keep going on your task but you got the roll pie 

More 

Reply
```

As you can see the comment part can be just one line or multiple lines.. And I want to store them into some structured data format like list in Python as below.

```
list = [Comment1, Comment2, Comment3, ...]
```

For this, I used 'open(file)' and then readlines() but the parsing and storing are very tough for me.

Comment: why are there * in your first example but not in your second?

Comment: What do you mean by "is tilted"?

Comment: You need to decide what distinguishes a comment from other stuff your not interested in. For instance in the examples given there is no spaces between lines of the comment. If this is always the case you can split a large block of test up using this, if not then you will need a distinguishing feature..

Comment: @JoranBeasley * is just typo

Comment: @tripleee I just made the comment part emphasized by tilting the sentences. It is trivial. Oh it just removed. I mean there is no tilting. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: @Greg Sure, I found some template I made from. For each unit, 1st line is for time, 2nd is for nickname then for some lines (one or more) for comments part and then last two lines for just trivial (More, Reply, Replies 4 Reply.. ect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
comments = re.split("(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})",open("some_file.txt").read().strip())
date_comment_pairs = zip(*[iter(comments)]*2)
comments_and_users = [x[1].split("More")[0].strip() for x in date_comment_pairs]
comments_alone = ["\n".join(x.splitlines()[1:]) for x in comments_and_users]
```

something like that maybe?

Comment: Thanks for new approach for me. But it only works in separating first line (time) from others. The total txt data consists of only one type of unit format.                                            I found some. For each unit, 1st line is for time, 2nd is for nickname then for some lines (one or more) for comments part and then last two lines for just trivial (More, Reply, Replies 4 Reply.. ect)

Comment: I figured you could figure out the rest on your own ... its pretty easy to separate the rest

Comment: Yeah. At first, I thought it will be easy. As I am not good at Python. Here, I used only readlines() or readline(). With these methods, I could not find proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: ok I added some more ... not it should be about what you want

Comment: Thanks. different perspective I've got from you. And almost I solve my  problems. Thanks again.